# Including the same PHP file twice or more

Tags: php

I just ran into a problem: I am trying to include a PHP file three times in the same page, but it doesn't seems to work at all. The HTML sheet at my test server is totally blank after the 1st run.

I'm using

```
<?php include("test.php"); ?>
```

3 times.

Any suggestions?

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php include("url.php") ?>&title=<?php  include("title.php") ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=700,height=350'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Facebook.</span><img src="images/f.png" width="32" height="32"></a>

<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php include("title.php") ?>+<?php include("url.php") ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=555,height=555'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Twitter.</span><img src="images/t.png" width="32" height="32"></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php include("url.php") ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=615,height=615'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Google+.</span><img src="images/g.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
```

test.php contains this:

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}

echo curPageURL();
```

Comment: Are you sure the file name and path are correct?  Is it including it correctly the first time?  You need a semicolon after the last parenthesis.

Comment: you need to write full path correctly and the extention along with your file name

Comment: yes, using the same "line", and the 1st one is correct.

Comment: could you give an exampel Rahul? Please.

Comment: I am using the same php include for all my "social media" links. for exampel: facebook.com/[URL] twitter.come/[URL} <?php include("url") ?>

Comment: So you are trying to include facebook and twitter in your page, right ?

Comment: yes, "the share links" with the url include

Comment: You still need a semicolon after the function call.. are you pasting your code here exactly as it appears in your production code? If so, fix it in your production code. If not, please paste your production code.

Comment: the "question" is updated with the code I am using.

Comment: This works like a charm :
<?php 
include 'test.php';
include 'test.php';
include 'test.php';
include 'test.php';
?>
So, if it does not work for you it is because you don't tell us everything !
If you want to include Facebook or Twitter please have a loog to iFrame

Comment: I am using it like this, <?php include("test.php") ?> <?php include("test.php") ?> <?php include("test.php") ?> at diffrent lines.

Comment: already tried it, didn't help

Comment: this works like a charm :
<body>
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
one
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
two
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
three
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
So where is your problem, you don't tell us everything we have to know to help...

Comment: Could you post the contents of test.php?

Comment: http://hemsidavisa.site90.net/BIKNew/index.php , see live exampel, check the page source at the end, only one of three is actully showing up.

Comment: @KurtBertil How is a live example supposed to help?  Its not like we can see the php code in `test.php`.

Comment: posted what the test.php contains in the "question"

Comment: already tried this <?php include'url.php'; ?> instead, didn't make a diffrens.

Comment: `?>` implies a semicolon (check http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) so `<?php include("title.php") ?>` is fine. Not that it's relevant

Comment: Including test.php multiple times is going to cause an error because it defines a function. A function can't be defined multiple times (which is what including test.php multiple times would do.)

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice A fatal error, at that.  Was about to post that as an answer, but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: I just figured out that it isn't the php include thats cusing the problem, it's the content of the "test.php" that does. when I remove it and replace it with the text, everything work as I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"but it doesn't seems to work at all" is the most pointless thing to ever write in a question. Explain what the issue is, or the error

what you are most likely getting is an error "Cannot redefine function curPageURL" or similar - once you create a function, you cannot define it again over and over.

There is little reason to be setting up your page like this - put your function definition in a single file, call it as many times as you want from your main page

Comment: the "error" at the moment is that the content of the "test.php" makes to php include to "die" when I am trying to run the same code multiple times.

Comment: @KurtBertil .. As noted in the comments above, it causes a fatal error to define the same function multiple times.  This answer fixes that, if you'd employ the solution defined within.

Comment: on a different note, using includes to echo parameter values in your urls is definitely not the way to go; set them to variables above your calls. Too long to explain why here; you should feel free to set that up as another question so people can explain

Comment: so if a make a new file that contains what test.php does and another one that calls that file, everything should be fine? is there an easy way to call it?

Comment: your code is set up correctly - just don't include the file 3 times. The function only needs to be defined once, you can call as many times as you like. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpfunctions.php

Answer (score 0):

It isn't good to include many times the same file.

Let's refactor the code a bit...

Create a new file 'data.php' with this:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}

function getUrl() {
    return 'YOUR URL HERE';
}

function getTitle() {
    return 'YOUR TITLE HERE';
}
?>
```

Now update your source to this:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php echo getUrl() ?>&title=<?php  echo getTitle() ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=700,height=350'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Facebook.</span><img src="images/f.png" width="32" height="32"></a>

<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo getTitle() ?>+<?php echo getUrl() ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=555,height=555'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Twitter.</span><img src="images/t.png" width="32" height="32"></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo getUrl() ?>" class="tooltip" onclick="open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=615,height=615'); return false;"><span>Dela sidan på Google+.</span><img src="images/g.png" width="32" height="32"></a>
```

And insted of call **include("test.php")** 3 times, call **curPageURL()**

I hope I have helped!